# R Data.table strange search issue. (unprintable chars?)

Tags: r, data.table

Dears,

I have a strange issue.
I have a data.table "harvest":

```
str(harvest)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  30005 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Date           : Date, format: "2014-07-08" ...
 $ Client         : Factor w/ 68 levels

etc...
```

Now

```
harvest[grepl("Belgilux",Client),]
```

yields 258 results

To find out the exact name of the Client I do :

```
harvest[grepl("Belgilux",Client),unique(Client)]
[1] N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A.
(out of 68 levels)
```

So far so good.

But if I do

```
harvest[Client=="N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A."]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 19 cols: Date,YearMonth,Month,Client,Project,Project.Code...
```

While I expected the same 258 results

```
levels(harvest$Client)[levels(harvest$Client)=="N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A."] <- "Replace Me"
```

Gives no result either.

When I do the same with any other Clientname, it returns the correct amount of results.

I tried to give you a reproducable setup, but there the issue is not seen.

```
dt=data.table(Client=c("N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A.", "Oh MyMedia","Testme","Oh MyMedia","N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A."),Value=c(1:5))
dt$Client<-as.factor(dt$Client)
```

My question is : is it possible that there are some unprintable chars in my "Client" string and how can i see this?
Any other approaches?

Comment: Because in the previous case with `grep` it matches any substring, but with `==` it is an exact match.  There could be some difference in the string to have an exact match.  For e.g. `"N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A."` have some characters that could be different.  You can copy from the `levels` and then do the `==`

Comment: If wrapping in parentheses fixes it `harvest[(Client=="N.V. L'ORÉAL Belgilux S.A.")]` then it is probably an auto-indexing bug. (If so, you'd want to get a reproducible example before reporting, I guess.)

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your reply. I copied it from levels but it makes no difference. I tried also with another client string copied from levels and there it works fine.

Comment: @Frank also big thank you for you reply. Wrapping up in parenthesis made no difference. Still no result.

Comment: Gents, I still couln't find an answer but I worked around the issue by approaching the level. levels(harvest$Client)[41]